# Access element in multi dimensional array?

Tags: solidity

I made a function to access element in multi dimensional array. But I am only getting one output. Why?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.1 <0.9.0;
contract myArray{
uint [][] ipadPriceRam =[[uint(1000),1200,1300],[uint(8),16,32]];
string [][] appleProduct=[["ipad","macbook","iphone"],["airpod","typec","headphone"]];
function getIpadPriceRam() public view returns(uint){
    return ipadPriceRam[0][1];
}
function appleProductAccess() public view returns(string memory){
    return appleProduct[1][1];
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get one output because the first dimension of `appleProduct[1][1]` points to the array `["airpod","typec","headphone"]`, and the second dimension of `appleProduct[1][1]` points to `typec`, or second element of the `["airpod","typec","headphone"]` array.

Comment: how to get output ipad and airpod

Comment: use "function appleProductAccess() public view returns(string memory){
    return appleProduct[0][0];
}" to get ipad

Comment: use "function appleProductAccess() public view returns(string memory){
    return appleProduct[1][0];
}" to get airpod

Comment: can i get two output in one function

Comment: "function appleProductAccess() public view returns(string memory, uint){
    return (appleProduct[1][0], ipadPriceRam[0][0]);
}". You can adjust the 1s and 0s in each multi-dimensional array to get what you want, based on your design.